# Is it possible to update only one shared file between repositories using git?

Tags: git

Suppose I have two repositories, `origin` and `upstream`. They are totally different repositories, and only share one file in common, call it `file.txt`. Upstream contains the latest changes for this `file.txt`, and suppose I want to update `origin`'s file.txt as well, based on `upstream` version.

Is it possible to do this with a git fetch then rebase or merge? To just fetch the updates of `file.txt` and update just that one file? Or is the simplist way to update the file to just do a copy paste?

Comment: I wouldnt name them origin and upstream if they are unrelated repositories with only one file in common, i would call them `A` and `B` or something more telling. And the short answer to your question is absolutely not.  But you dont need a copy paste either.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is probably just to do `git fetch upstream main`, `git checkout upstream/main common.txt`, `git commit`. This is convenient, but loses the real change history of common.txt, which may or may not be important for you.

To preserve the file's history, you can do a merge like this:

```
git fetch upstream main
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories --no-commit -s ours upstream/main
git checkout upstream/main common.txt
git commit
```

- `git fetch` just fetches the remote, like normal
- `git merge`

  - `--allow-unrelated-histories` stops git from complaining about the gits being unrelated. This should *only be required the first time*, since future updates *will* have related histories.
  - `--no-commit` stops the command from creating the commit for us. Not a huge deal -- we could've ended with `git commit --amend` instead -- but it's nice to not risk committing/uploading an incorrect merge.
  - `-s ours` is very important: it makes the merge ignore the content of `upstream/main` completely.
- `git checkout` takes the common file from upstream, completely overwriting any changes that may have happened in our local repo. I assume this is what you wanted.
- `git commit` creates the merge commit for you.

Here's a script to demo the process, showing two updates with a local change in between, and the git history at each point. It stops after each operation to let you see what's happening.

```
#!/bin/bash

PAGER=

function show() {
    git log --graph --oneline --decorate
    git blame common.txt
    ls -lh
    git grep --color=always .
    read -p "Press ENTER to continue..."
    echo -e '\n\n\n\n'
}

function update() {
    git fetch upstream main
    git merge --allow-unrelated-histories --no-commit -s ours upstream/main
    git checkout upstream/main common.txt
    git commit --no-edit
    show
}

set -ex

rm -rf mine other

mkdir other
pushd other
git init -b main
echo 'goodbye world' > common.txt
echo 'this is junk' > unimportant.txt
git add common.txt unimportant.txt
git commit -m 'first commit in other'
popd

mkdir mine
pushd mine
git init -b main
echo 'hello world' > common.txt
echo 'lorem ipsum' > lorem.txt
git add common.txt lorem.txt
git commit -m 'first commit in mine'
git remote add upstream ../other
update
popd

pushd other
echo 'hello again world' >> common.txt
git commit -a -m 'Add another greeting'
echo 'more junk' >> unimportant.txt
git commit -a -m 'Add more junk'
echo 'hello AGAIN world' >> common.txt
echo 'even more junk' >> unimportant.txt
git commit -a -m 'Add a third greeting and lots of junk'
popd

pushd mine
echo 'moar!' > another_file.txt
git add another_file.txt
git commit -m 'Add another file'
echo 'dolor amet' >> lorem.txt
git commit -a -m 'Add more latin'
show
update
popd
```

...and its output (though running locally will give you colors, so do try that):

```
onefile$ ./experiment.sh 
+ rm -rf mine other
+ mkdir other
+ pushd other
/tmp/onefile/other /tmp/onefile
+ git init -b main
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/onefile/other/.git/
+ echo 'goodbye world'
+ echo 'this is junk'
+ git add common.txt unimportant.txt
+ git commit -m 'first commit in other'
[main (root-commit) 6e0aabf] first commit in other
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 common.txt
 create mode 100644 unimportant.txt
+ popd
/tmp/onefile
+ mkdir mine
+ pushd mine
/tmp/onefile/mine /tmp/onefile
+ git init -b main
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/onefile/mine/.git/
+ echo 'hello world'
+ echo 'lorem ipsum'
+ git add common.txt lorem.txt
+ git commit -m 'first commit in mine'
[main (root-commit) 2aa2411] first commit in mine
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 common.txt
 create mode 100644 lorem.txt
+ git remote add upstream ../other
+ update
+ git fetch upstream main
remote: Enumerating objects: 4, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), 269 bytes | 269.00 KiB/s, done.
From ../other
 * branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]      main       -> upstream/main
+ git merge --allow-unrelated-histories --no-commit -s ours upstream/main
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested
+ git checkout upstream/main common.txt
Updated 1 path from 262d970
+ git commit --no-edit
[main 09371f1] Merge remote-tracking branch 'upstream/main'
+ show
+ git log --graph --oneline --decorate
*   09371f1 (HEAD -> main) Merge remote-tracking branch 'upstream/main'
|\  
| * 6e0aabf (upstream/main) first commit in other
* 2aa2411 first commit in mine
+ git blame common.txt
^6e0aabf (Snild Dolkow 2023-08-03 19:35:33 +0200 1) goodbye world
+ ls -lh
total 8.0K
-rw-r--r-- 1 snild snild 14 Aug  3 19:35 common.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 snild snild 12 Aug  3 19:35 lorem.txt
+ git grep --color=always .
common.txt:goodbye world
lorem.txt:lorem ipsum
+ read -p 'Press ENTER to continue...'
Press ENTER to continue...
+ echo -e '\n\n\n\n'





+ popd
/tmp/onefile
+ pushd other
/tmp/onefile/other /tmp/onefile
+ echo 'hello again world'
+ git commit -a -m 'Add another greeting'
[main ece2b84] Add another greeting
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
+ echo 'more junk'
+ git commit -a -m 'Add more junk'
[main 1c637d7] Add more junk
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
+ echo 'hello AGAIN world'
+ echo 'even more junk'
+ git commit -a -m 'Add a third greeting and lots of junk'
[main baffb43] Add a third greeting and lots of junk
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
+ popd
/tmp/onefile
+ pushd mine
/tmp/onefile/mine /tmp/onefile
+ echo 'moar!'
+ git add another_file.txt
+ git commit -m 'Add another file'
[main a3bdf2a] Add another file
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 another_file.txt
+ echo 'dolor amet'
+ git commit -a -m 'Add more latin'
[main 3140c28] Add more latin
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
+ show
+ git log --graph --oneline --decorate
* 3140c28 (HEAD -> main) Add more latin
* a3bdf2a Add another file
*   09371f1 Merge remote-tracking branch 'upstream/main'
|\  
| * 6e0aabf (upstream/main) first commit in other
* 2aa2411 first commit in mine
+ git blame common.txt
^6e0aabf (Snild Dolkow 2023-08-03 19:35:33 +0200 1) goodbye world
+ ls -lh
total 12K
-rw-r--r-- 1 snild snild  6 Aug  3 19:35 another_file.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 snild snild 14 Aug  3 19:35 common.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 snild snild 23 Aug  3 19:35 lorem.txt
+ git grep --color=always .
another_file.txt:moar!
common.txt:goodbye world
lorem.txt:lorem ipsum
lorem.txt:dolor amet
+ read -p 'Press ENTER to continue...'
Press ENTER to continue...
+ echo -e '\n\n\n\n'





+ update
+ git fetch upstream main
remote: Enumerating objects: 13, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (13/13), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
remote: Total 10 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (10/10), 900 bytes | 900.00 KiB/s, done.
From ../other
 * branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD
   6e0aabf..baffb43  main       -> upstream/main
+ git merge --allow-unrelated-histories --no-commit -s ours upstream/main
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested
+ git checkout upstream/main common.txt
Updated 1 path from 4ddbaec
+ git commit --no-edit
[main 1d1bad8] Merge remote-tracking branch 'upstream/main'
+ show
+ git log --graph --oneline --decorate
*   1d1bad8 (HEAD -> main) Merge remote-tracking branch 'upstream/main'
|\  
| * baffb43 (upstream/main) Add a third greeting and lots of junk
| * 1c637d7 Add more junk
| * ece2b84 Add another greeting
* | 3140c28 Add more latin
* | a3bdf2a Add another file
* | 09371f1 Merge remote-tracking branch 'upstream/main'
|\| 
| * 6e0aabf first commit in other
* 2aa2411 first commit in mine
+ git blame common.txt
^6e0aabf (Snild Dolkow 2023-08-03 19:35:33 +0200 1) goodbye world
ece2b841 (Snild Dolkow 2023-08-03 19:35:34 +0200 2) hello again world
baffb431 (Snild Dolkow 2023-08-03 19:35:34 +0200 3) hello AGAIN world
+ ls -lh
total 12K
-rw-r--r-- 1 snild snild  6 Aug  3 19:35 another_file.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 snild snild 50 Aug  3 19:35 common.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 snild snild 23 Aug  3 19:35 lorem.txt
+ git grep --color=always .
another_file.txt:moar!
common.txt:goodbye world
common.txt:hello again world
common.txt:hello AGAIN world
lorem.txt:lorem ipsum
lorem.txt:dolor amet
+ read -p 'Press ENTER to continue...'
Press ENTER to continue...
+ echo -e '\n\n\n\n'





+ popd
/tmp/onefile
```

As you can see, this method of merging preserves the upstream history of common.txt, while not affecting any other files.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't do that period. Any attempted merge or rebase is going to try to combine the projects and their histories etc.

The easiest way to do what you describe is not done through a copy and paste either..  Its done all at the command line.

```
git clone <originURL> origin
git clone <upstreamURL> upstream
cp upstream/file.txt origin/file.txt # adjust paths as appropriate
cd origin && git add file.txt && git commit -m'updated from upstream` && git push && cd ..
```

you could get fancier with the commit message and put the appropriate commit id from upstream into it.

for further updates: instead of cloning each you just have to do a `git pull` in each first.